# What is the meaning of 'of + ~ing' in the following sentence?

Tags: gerunds, prepositional-phrases

What is the meaning of 'of + ~ing' in the following sentence,

> "The quickest way of contacting the police station is to use your
>   cellphone."

Does it mean

> "The quickest way that we contact the police station is to use your
>   cellphone"

or

> "The quickest way for us to contact the police station is to use your
>   cellphone"

or

> "The quickest way of us to contact the police station is to use your
>   cellphone"

?

Does "of + ~ ing" have the meaning of an omitted subject not in the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English is notorious for using the -ing ending (which normally denotes something being done in the present progressive tense) in place if the verb's *infinitive* form. The sentence would most accurately be read as:

> "The quickest way *to contact* the police station is to use your cellphone."

It should also be noted that the *your* in *"to use your cellphone."* is also impersonal (in colloquial English). The #1 most literal version of the sentence would be:

> "The quickest way *for one to contact* the police station *would be* to use *their* cellphone."